# Angular 2 Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

I have tried many propositions on fixing this error here on stackoverflow, but now I just need to ask as I have spent many hours with literally getting nowhere now.

I have this simple Service:

```
constructor(private http: Http, private tokenResolver: TokenResolver) {}

public getEventHistory(): Observable<heatmapElement[]> {

  this.tokenResolver.getToken(true).subscribe(token => {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.result = this.http.get(this.restApi, new RequestOptions({headers: headers}))
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  });

  return this.result as Observable<heatmapElement[]>;
}
```

I want to get the data using :

```
public demoData: heatmapElement[] =[];

getEventHistory(): void {
  this.eventHistoryService.getEventHistory()
                          .subscribe(data => this.demoData = data,);
}
```

This creates a error that I just cant seem to fix:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:5555/app/dashboard/dashboard.html:13:8 caused by: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

I would be very grateful for help, 
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't return a result of `async call` outside its `subscribe` method.

If you want to return Observable from `getEventHistory()`, you can change `subscribe` to `map` or `switchMap`.

```
public getEventHistory(): Observable<heatmapElement[]> {

  return this.tokenResolver.getToken(true).switchMap(token => {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.get(this.restApi, new RequestOptions({headers: headers}));
  })
  .map((res: Response) => res.json() as heatmapElement[]);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this code will work, it is not returning anything in the scope of `getEventHistory()` method.

Comment: @echonax agreed.  I was tring to change `subscribe` to map. :) and return `this.tokenResolver.getToken`  but not sure whether this will work.  :P

Comment: Thank you for you're proposal, but sadly it doesn't work, just as echonax stated.

Comment: Ohhh god! Thank you so much! I have spent so many hours on trying to fix this!

Answer (score 4):

Odd as this may be, in my instance, after spending lots of time debugging, it turned out, I was using an Output(`@Output`) `EventEmitter` property to handle a custom event, and Angular did not recognize my property or custom event property when passed on a template:

e.g

`<custom-component (keydownEvent)="someFunctoin()"></custom-component>`

The issue with doing the above is(as far as my issue is concerned) `(keydownEvent)` is not a valid Event handler, but why the heck does it work in development and not when you've built your project. Even MORE strange, `ng build --prod` does not issue any errors or warning!

**Solution**

`<custom-component keydown="someFunctoin()"></custom-component>`

**Where do subscriber/subscription related errors come in?**

Well, as you'd imagine, one subscribed to the `EventEmitter` - so I guess that's where the correlation is

Comment: Thank you, I got the same issue with the event emitter, wasted lot of time looking at the service methods that I used. Your answer solved my issue

Comment: Same issue, but I solved that creating (not just declaring) the event emmit in the child component. Example: @Output() closePopUp: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();